# Exporting C++ code as a DLL and import using C#?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, dll

I have a program written in C++ with a main function that calls a bunch of other C++ classes/functions.

I am new to C++ (been a python programmer), so I'm wondering - What are the steps I need to follow to be able to export this as a DLL that is importable from a C# program? Any suggestions?

Comment: This is about a C interface, and has nothing to do with either the source or destination language.

Comment: You have not written it in "C/C++". That language doesn't even exist.

Comment: Sorry - I added back the tags because my C++ code contains some classes and I am also interested in knowing how to deal with these class and import this once I compile it into a C# program.

Comment: @WTP: Changed it... Got into a very bad habit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your C++ classes to be usable in a C# application you will need to use COM or target the CLR in your C++ program (i.e., use C++/CLI).

If you simply have some functions in the C++ DLL that you want to call from C# that take POD type arguments then declare each function as `extern "C"` to avoid name mangling and use the `DLLImport` attribute to import the function.  [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net) is a great resource here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only exporting plain functions, not classes, you can [p/invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) them. if ypu really need the classes, you have to write your project as a [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379617%28VS.80%29.aspx) and reference it in your c# project like any other .NET assembly.