# is it possible to import a dynamic library written in c++ into a c# program

Tags: c#, c++, dll

All in the title really. I have a library, written in c++ and compiled into a dll. I would like to use this functionality in a c# program. Is it possible to use the classes/functions from the library straight from c#, would I need to write some wrapper code to use it in a managed environment? Can they be used in an unsafe context? Sorry if this is a silly question - I'm a c++ programmer trying to move over to c#.

p.s. the library is from a third party, so I cannot port it direct to c# even if I had the time.

Comment: read [this SO q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333159/exporting-c-code-as-a-dll-and-import-using-c)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on *how* the C++ dll exports it's functionality.

If it's through C++ classes, then  your best bet is to build a wrapper in C++/CLI that will consume the C++ classes and expose .NET classes to interact with them.

If it's through "classic" C-style functions, then you can use p-invoke to call the functions directly.  It would be similar to the ways system DLLs like `System32` and `User32` are accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible!
First add the reference to System.Runtime.InteropServices:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

After you have to import the function on the external Dll:

```
    [DllImport("ExternalDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "FunctionNameOnExtDll")]
    public static extern CSharpDataType FunctionNameOnExtDll(ParameterDataType ParameterName);
```

And finally use it!!

```
FunctionNameOnExtDll(Parameter);
```

Comment: You're assuming that the DLL exposes C-style functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just knowing the signature of the functions you want to call and use System.Runtime.InteropServices facilities.
To help, use this tool [PInvoke Interop Assistant](https://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) that can help define data structures to be passed in calls.